# Unable to Install android Emulators on windows 10

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, emulation

Please help me in installation of Emulators for android on Windows 10..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HvA4.jpg

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First download **Android Studio**.
Then press
[image: avd Manager]
(AVD Manager)

Later, press "+Create Virtual Device" button which is in leftbottom corner.